# Why Django form didn check unique of form field?

Tags: python, html, django, forms

Method is_valid didnt check  unique of form and when i try to create new item its just do nothing.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class Links(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Пользователь')
    long_url = models.CharField('Длинная ссылка', max_length=300)
    short_url = models.SlugField('Сокращенная ссылка', max_length=50, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField('Название для ссылки', max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

field short_url have unique=True

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Links
from .forms import AddLinkForm

def links(request):
    return render(request, 'main/main_page.html')


class LinksList(ListView):
    model = Links
    template_name = 'links/links.html'
    ordering = ['-id']

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(LinksList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        links = Links.objects.filter(user=user)
        form = AddLinkForm
        ctx['form'] = form
        ctx['links'] = links
        return ctx

    def post(self, request, *agrs, **kwargs):

        post = request.POST.copy()
        post['user'] = request.user
        request.POST = post

        form = AddLinkForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        return redirect('links')
```

i try to use is_valid but when im testing it form let me entry not unic word, i press add it but page reload.It shoud work but i cant understand what is wrong

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Links


class AddLinkForm(forms.ModelForm):

    long_url = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        label='Длинная ссылка',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Введите длинную ссылку'})
    )

    short_url = forms.SlugField(
        required=True,
        label='Сокращенная ссылка',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Введите сокращенную ссылку'})
    )

    title = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        label='Введти название для вашей ссылки',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Введите название здя вашей ссылки'})
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Links
        fields = ['user', 'long_url', 'short_url', 'title']
        widgets = {'user': forms.HiddenInput()}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', ':')
        super(AddLinkForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

why it dosent work?

Comment: There's nothing obvious here that would make the unique validation fail - are you sure that the short url you are entering already exists?

Comment: I tested it all this time and i can say that noone validation work. Foe example, when i try to pun link that have lenth more then 300 symbols in long_url field and have unic slug in short_url, it also didnt show error and dont put note in the database

Comment: I printed form.errors in console and get "<ul class="errorlist"><li>short_url<ul class="errorlist"><li>Links с таким Сокращенная ссылка уже существует.</li></ul></li></ul>
" So i have erro but Django dont show it on the page. how to fix it?

Comment: You can print it in the template with {{ form.errors }} - looks like that’s your not unique constraint? Google translate is a little off

Comment: Its about unic constraint

Comment: {{ form.errors }} didnt help me. Form just reload and get empty

Comment: Isn't unique constraint what you want?

Comment: I get some hint on, I need to use ```        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('links')
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)``` but this method dont work, or i need to create this?